# I bought two new shock absorbers but one of them is much softer and slower. Is it bad? (video attached)

Tags: suspension, shock-absorber, struts

It also does not go up fully if I put some weight on it.

Video: https://youtu.be/1CpawflyGjs

Car is scion tc. Both struts are the same brand/line.